# Angular2 [ngClass] Conditional fails with Spaces

Tags: angular, angular-ng-class

I have an ngClass conditional that functions fine on class names without spaces, but when i try to do something like below and i toggle isTrue on button click, the class changes from "btn btn-primary" to "btn-default". The space in there seems to be throwing it off. Am i missing something

```
[ngClass]="{ 'btn btn-default': isTrue, 'btn btn-primary': !isTrue}"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take the common one out, and have the rest of the expression in an `ngClass` directive

```
class="btn" [ngClass]="{ 'btn-default': isTrue, 'btn-primary': !isTrue}"
```